# React Native Integration with Android Pay(android) and Apple Pay(iOS)

Tags: react-native, android-pay, applepay

There is no official documentation around Android and Apple Pay integration with RN.
Some of the libraries that are present are not been up to date. I'm afraid those will fail with RN 0.61.
Any leads/suggestions on how to go about:

1. integrating Android and Apple Pay with `RN 0.61`
2. handling cancellations/refunds under a certain time limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ive used react-native-iap library to implement the in -app purchases i.e android and apple pay integration. It's pretty easy. Just follow the article and voila, it will be done.

[RN-IAP](https://medium.com/@abhayg772/implementing-in-app-purchase-in-react-native-application-3798ca2de5bb)

Below is the package of library ive used.

[rn-iap-library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-iap)

Hope it helps, feel free for doubts.

Comment: For anybody looking into this in 2023 - The iOS implementation in rn-iap-library uses StoreKit under the hood which differs from PassKit, the underlying API for Apple Pay. If you want Apple Pay, you won't get it with rn-iap-library.